# How to add transition effects to a project in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and ran into a problem.
My project randomly generates a number ranging from 1 to 3, and it shows different content depending on that number.
Everything works, but I would like to add that when I click, the content appears by changing the opacity each time I click the button

How can I go about it?
I tried to change the setOpacity parameter in onClick but didn't get the result

My code:

Main.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Random from "./Random";
class Main extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    value:  0
  };
}
changeValue = () => {
  const min = Math.ceil(1);
  const max = Math.floor(4);
  let xd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  this.setState({ value: xd });
  console.log(this.state.value);
};
render() {
  return (
    <div onLoad={this.changeValue} className="card">
      <Random data={this.state.value} change={this.changeValue.bind(this)} />
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default Main;
```

Random.js :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import sad from './sad.png';
import angry from './angry.png';
import haha from './haha.png';
const Random = (props) => {
 


  if (props.data === 0) {
    return (
      <div className="macius"  >
        <h1>Random option</h1>
        <div>
          <span>
            <h3>Click Losuj!</h3>
            <button onClick={props.change}>LOSUJ</button>
          </span>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  } else if (props.data === 1) {
    return (
        <div className="maciek">
        <h1>Angry</h1>
        <div>
          <span>
          <img src={angry} alt="smutny"/>
            <button onClick={props.change}>LOSUJ</button>
          </span>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  } else if (props.data === 2) {
    return (
        <div className="maciek">
        <h1>Sad</h1>
        <div>
          <span>
            <img src={sad} alt="smutny"/>
            <button onClick={props.change}>LOSUJ</button>
          </span>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  } else if (props.data === 3) {
    return (
        <div className="maciek">
        <h1>HaHa</h1>
        <div>
          <span>
          <img src={haha} alt="smutny"/>
            <button onClick={props.change}>LOSUJ</button>
          </span>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>error</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Random;
```

Comment: The question seems slightly unclear. What do you mean by "the content appears by changing the opacity"? What is the "content" you are referring to? Do you want transition effects? Could you also mention where you tried to make the "setOpacity" change on your code.

Comment: @HassanNaqvi Thank for answer! My point is that div className = "maciek" had the default opacity: 0, only after pressing the 'losuj' button it had the value of opacity: 1, but that the second press of div would load the same (first opacity: 0 then opacity: 1) only with different content in the div className = "maciek".
I tried to do it on principle ` const [opacity,setOpacity] = React.useState(0) and function changeOpacity() {setOpacity(1)} with transition: 1 s in css , but this changes the opacity to 1 permanently and only works with one click. I hope I explained it well;)